# American words for gas stoves

Tags: american-english, vocabulary

Please take a look at the following two images:

[image: Image # 1]

[image: Image # 2]

In India, it's customary to refer to the thing in the first image as a "gas stove" and the second as a"cooking range" or "hob." Is it the same in American homes?

Comment: Most American homes wouldn't have a stand-alone stovetop like that. We mostly have stove/oven combinations. If you said "*gas stove*" to an American he'd probably picture the *stovetop* if a gas-fired oven. If I had to give a name to the top picture, I'd call it a "camping stove", maybe? Cooking range is perfectly fine here (though used more by advertisers than homeowners), but *hob* is generally unknown.

Comment: So "stovetop" is the word preferred in American kitchens and they are not standalone but rather come "pre-installed" with the kitchen. Am I right in assuming this? Also, which of the two would be more common out there? Gas powered stovetops or non-gas stovetops (electric maybe?)?

Comment: Well, they come pre-installed with the *oven* (or range), and to the extent many homes are built and sold with kitchen appliances pre-installed, yes, the stovetop on the oven comes with that. On other words, it's a *stovetop* because it's a *stove* and also a *top* (for the oven).

Comment: But if I have to specifically talk about the "stove" portion of the stovetop/oven combo, what's the word I should use? Say, I am asking you to place something on top of the burner to heat it up (as against inside the oven). Would you just say, "place it on the stovetop"? Please condense your posts as an answer. And thanks for your patience!

Comment: Nope, then you'd just say plain old *stove*. I'm just trying to give you a word for the broken-out unit deputed in the first image, which is correctly and technically called a stove. The problem is saying "*stove*" to an American would not conjure up a picture like your first, because we generally don't have those things. Except in transitory situations like camping or places which don't have a full kitchen.

Comment: Thanks once again. Am looking forward to your answer so I could accept it and close the thread.

Comment: Amit, afraid I'm going to have to disappoint you on that count: I'm headed out for a bit, so I'll be limited to what I can easily compose on my phone. Sorry about that!

Comment: "gas stove" is correct in AmE. If it's electric, it's an "electric stove". If you don't have to distinguish (you're pointing at one in a kitchen) you'd just call it "the stove". People selling these things will more likely call it a "range", but people actually using them will more likely call it a "stove".

Comment: the first pic is a double bunson burner!

Answer (score 3):

According to OxfordLearnersDictionary; [stove:](http://www.oxfordlearnersdictionaries.com/definition/english/stove)

> - (especially North American English) (British English also cooker) (North American English also range) a large piece of equipment for cooking food, containing an oven and gas or electric rings on top.  - She put a pan of water on the stove.
> - (North American English, British English) Most people don't want to spend hours slaving over a hot stove(= cooking).

[Range](http://www.oxfordlearnersdictionaries.com/definition/english/range_1):

> - (North American English) : stove.
> - stove with spaces for cooking a number of things at the same time.
>
>   - Cook the meat on a low heat on top of the range.

Comment: This does not seem to answer the question at all. It gives definitions of *stove* and *range*, but that was not what was asked.

Comment: I don't think that's what the question is. He is asking what words (plural) Americans use to **distinguish** the two kinds of gas stove shown in the picture. At least that's my interpretation. Admittedly, the question could be clearer.

Answer (score 1):

Here's my take on first photo. I think it could be considered a gas hot plate.

http://www.foodservicewarehouse.com/equipment/commercial-hot-plates/c3544.aspx

The second photo is, as previous posters stated, a gas stove or range.

*And now I correct myself with the link below*

http://www.ehow.com/about_5374912_oven-vs-range.html