# Difference between "stove" and "range"?

Tags: american-english

What is the difference between "stove" and "range"?

Does one or the other imply a set of burners for heating food *situated above an oven*?

I'm primarily interested in answers for American English.

Related existing question that didn't directly answer my question: [American words for gas stoves](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/210512/american-words-for-gas-stoves)

Comment: What did the dictionary tell you?

Comment: [Collins](http://www.thefreedictionary.com/range) indicates that at least some people use 'range' (the kitchen fitting usage) as a hyponym of 'stove': Cookery: a large stove with burners and one or more ovens, usually heated by solid fuel. In the virtual collection of stoves I've built up, the term 'range' is normally applied (and restricted to) large cooking stoves (often manufactured in the US), thus multi-compartment old woodburners, Agas etc, and gas and electric cookers larger than the standard '4 jet' varieties.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Not sure if this is helpful or it answers your question, this [Quora answer](https://www.quora.com/What-is-the-difference-between-a-stove-and-a-range) mentions the difference and usage:

> A stove only has cooking burners; a range includes a broiler and bake
>   element. In the USA the words among consumers for stove, range, and
>   oven are used interchangeably. (Cris Smith)

Comment: Hello, welcome to English Language and Usage. A link-only answer is discouraged here because the link can become invalid if the linked page changes. Please include essential parts of the link in your post and make sure that you take the [tour](http://english.stackexchange.com/tour) and visit our [help center](http://english.stackexchange.com/help) for additional guidance.